# simple non-regex nginx location mapping

Tags: nginx

I have a domain www.example.com and here is the config of my nginx

```
    location /data {
    root   /var/www.example.com/html;
    index  index.html;
}
```

when I hit http://www.example.com/data, I expect the the index.html in folder /var/www.example.com/html will be shown up but it just doesn't.

The location of path is quite simple even without a regex (my requirements is really this simple). What did I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to add `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` to your hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `alias` instead of `root`. With `root`, the URI is appended to the path specified, so in your case `http://www.example.com/data` becomes `/var/www/example.com/html/data/data`.

With `alias /var/www/example.com/html/data`, it becomes `/var/www/example.com/html/data`.